# How to update widget manually?

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I want to update widget manually. So, I add in an AndroidManifest filter:

```
 <action android:name="com.myapp.WIDGET_UPDATE"/>
```

And I try to send broadcasts from adb console like this

```
am broadcast -a com.myapp.WIDGET_UPDATE
```

But nothing happens. Here is the code from onReceive:

```
public class myapp extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private final static IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.myapp.WIDGET_UPDATE");

    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateWidget(context);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put one button in **layout_wid.xml** file.

in `onUpdate()` you have to find the id of your button.and put click event to refresh your widget

```
Intent imageview2Intent= new Intent(context, WatchWidget.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, imageview2Intent,0);         
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);
```

you try this way.

Comment: I have refresh on click in inUpdate. I need update widget from different app.

Comment: can you explain more.